# How does chaining assignment operator work in this situatio

Tags: javascript, object, assignment-operator

I saw this somewhat strange assignment operator chaining somewhere and I've been trying to understand how this is possible, but I seem unable to wrap my head around it.

```
var a = {n: 1};

var b = a;  

a.x = a = {n: 2};

console.log(a.x); // undefined  
console.log(b.x); // {n: 2}
```

Answer (score 4):

The internal reference value for `a.x` — the "target" of the assignment `a.x = a` — is calculated before the assignments happen. The target of the assignment is therefore the "x" property on the *old* value of `a`, which is the same as `b`.  The new value of `a` doesn't have an "x" property, so that's undefined. However, the assignment gave an "x" property to the old value of `a`, which is the current value of `b`.

If you like "language lawyering", you can see a description [here in the ES2015 spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) for the `=` operator and how it works. Note that in step 1, something called **lref** is determined. That's the "target" I mentioned in the above paragraph, and note that it happens *before* the right-hand "assignment expression" is computed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = {n: 1};

var b = a;   // since a is an object b holds the reference of 

a.x = a = {n: 2};
```

- `a = {n : 2}` this changes the value of a, so as the memory reference is changed due to assignment
- `a.x = a` a now points to new memory reference whereas `a.x` still refer to old reference ( as it is evaluated before right hand side expression )

Comment: But `b.x` is *not* `undefined`.

Comment: @Pointy can you please explain a bit where i am getting it wrong ? would love to correct myself

Comment: The key is that in `a.x = a = {n: 2}` the *lref* `a.x` is computed *before* the right hand side of the leftmost `=` is computed. Thus the "memory location" for the right hand side of that, where `a` changes, happens before `a` changes. Thus even though it still says `a.x` it's effectively referring to `b.x` because be is the only remaining reference to the *old* value of `a`.

Comment: @Pointy oh makes sense, thanks for info learnt something new :)